# Cheap hotel or B&B in Zürich

Tags: budget, accommodation, hotels, zurich

Looking for this summer to spend a couple of days in Zürich.

I am looking for a basic **hotel**, with a double room.

The prices on for hotels / apartments on booking.com seem kind of high for me (cheapest place I found around 80 € / 99 CHF).

Any websites that offer a more affordable accommodation? **B&B or private apartments** also.

Any places around Zürich which are cheaper and which are well connected by public means of transportation with city center?

Comment: What kind of accommodation are you looking for? There is a wide range from hostels to world-class hotels. Also concerning food: there is a huge range.

Comment: @ValentinDespa Hi, welcome to Travel.SE. Your question currently is very broad and vague. Please try to edit it with more details so that it can be reopened. For instance, what is 'expensive' for you?

Comment: Also note that Switzerland is an expensive country. You will not find anything very cheap there (compared to accommodation prices in most European countries).

Comment: Jonik is right. Moreover if you come from a Euro zone country you will suffer from the disadvantageous exchange rate. This makes it even more expensive.

Comment: However the Euro is getting stronger again, so the situation isn't as bad as it used to be some months ago.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException My question was indeed vague, but answers are possible. Did you read the term "Cheap accommodation". By cheap do you really thing I mean  world-class hotels or just a simple place to stay for a couple of nights. Purpose of this website is providing useful info, not hitting people in the head when they are unclear about something.

Comment: @ValentinDespa Everybody has a different opinion what cheap means. As you can see in our FAQs the purpose of this site is to provide objective answers to question that are answerable.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException is my question now answerable?

Comment: So for example in your first version, you didn't specify that you're also looking for B&B or that you're looking for something below 80€. But now, I think the question is answerable, at least the part about the accommodation. The food part is still quite vague.

Comment: I've edited to remove the food section because it was too vague.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First a quick note: Switzerland in general, and Zurich particularly can be very expensive. It is one of the most expensive countries in whole Europe and because of the strong Swiss franc, the exchange rates aren't very good at the moment. On the other hand, Zurich is quite a small city, and the public transport is quite good and reliable. So you can be in the center quite fast, if you decide to stay a little bit out of Zurich to save some money. Generally, if you want to stay in the city, I would recommend to stay around Langstrasse or Niederdorf if you want to party, and to stay Wipkingen, Altstetten, or Kreis 6 (District 6) if you want to relax a little bit more. Schwamedingen, Affoltern or Seebach are also okay, but they are a little bit further away from the city center.

So if you're looking for bargains, you have essentially two possibilities. Either private accommodations, such as B&B or "cheap" hostels:

### B&B

[Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/) has also quite a few accommodations for Zurich. The cheapest starts around 10 USD for a night. Basically all neighborhoods inside the city itself are more or less close to the city center, since Zurich is not really big and well-connected by public transport. You might want to avoid the areas Affoltern, Seebach and Schwamendingen.

### Hostel

There are also some hostels in Zurich. If you check [hostelworld](http://www.hostelworld.com), private double rooms [start around 45 CHF per night if you want to stay in Kloten](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Hotel-Welcome-Inn/Zurich/10364?dateFrom=23%20Jan%202013&dateTo=26%20Jan%202013&sc_sau=avdc&sc_pos=2) where the airport is. There are quite a lot of trains to the city center, and it takes around 10-15 minutes. If you really want to stay in the city center itself, you can expect to pa at least 60 CHF. For example [this hostel](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/City-Backpacker-Hostel-Biber/Zurich/33226?dateFrom=23%20Jan%202013&dateTo=26%20Jan%202013&sc_sau=avdc&sc_pos=3) is located in the Niederdorf, where a lot of bars are located and you're in walking distance of all major sights. If you're interested in nightlife and going out, you might also consider to stay in the hostel [Langstars](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Langstars/Zurich/52531?dateFrom=01%20Jul%202013&dateTo=04%20Jul%202013). It is located directly over a bar in the Langstrasse where a lot of bars are located. Don't be scared by the prostitutes, drug dealers or drunk people you see there, it is not dangerous at all. But be aware, I would only take an accomodation in this area, if I'm interested in nightlife, because there is always a lot of noise almost 24/7.

Comment: In the end Airbnb provided the best solution for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

As additional, below indicated YHA Zurich link might be helpful as well:
http://www.youthhostel.ch/en/hostels/zurich